# SEF Суффикс на определёных страницах

Tags: joomla

Здравствуйте! В joomla 2.5 в общих настройках есть возможность включения SEF суффикса (.html), который отображается в конце ЧПУ адреса страницы. Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы этот суффикс будет виден только на определённых страницах, например:

```
http://мой-домен/категория-статьи/
http://мой-домен/категория-статьи/конкретная-статья.html
```

Т.е. если ссылка идёт категорию материалов, суффикс .html не ставится, а вот если это конкретный материал, товарная позиция и т.п. - ставится (только не редиректом).

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, нельзя. Установка суффикса URL применяется на все страницы и скрыть на определенных страницах нельзя. Либо включить - либо выключить. Ибо так построена CMS.

Comment: НЕТ можно! Нужно выровнять ручки, и сесть чутка переписать скриптов пару!

Comment: Ув. @Palmervan, в таком случае можно пререписать joomla под свой лад в свою CMS...

Comment: у меня рука не дрогнет брать какие то коды с джумлы :)

Comment: По этому приходим к выводу - использовать другую/свою CMS, либо довольствоваться тем, что есть.